# Near Real Time Ingesting data from sql table to Elastic index

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch

We have ETL process which ingest data every 5 mins once from different source system(as400,orcale,sap etc) into our sqlserver database, and from there we ingest data into elastic index every 5 mins so that both are in sync.
I wanted to tighten the timeframe to seconds rather than 5 mins and i wanted to make sure they both are in sync all time.

I am using control log table to make sure elastic ingestion and SSIS ETL are not running at the same time, so that we might go out of sync. which is very poor solution and not allowing me to achieve near real time data capture

I am looking for better solution to sync sqlserver database and elastic index in near real time rather than doing manually.

Note:I am using python scripts for pumping the data from sql to elastic index currently.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have an [event stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_stream_processing) coming out of your database or even directly out of the SSIS package run (which might actually be simpler to implement) that feeds directly into your elastic search index.  ELK handles streaming log files so should handle an event stream pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @Phils, do you have any reference documents or link that i can deep dive ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You could have a task in SSIS that export the stream by appending to a file(s). Then use [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) to transfer the data which is what I use to transfer logfiles.